# How to call gsub on a string for changing the last set of characters if it doesn't fit into a character class

Tags: ruby, regex

Regexs always give me problems. I would like to be able to do the following:

```
[10] pry(main)> "a-c---".gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]$/,'x')
=> "a-c--x"
```

so that it gives me:

```
=>"a-cxxx"
```

rather than:

```
=> "a-c--x"  # <- it would need to know that c fits within character class
```

How would I do this? I think the $ checks for ONLY the last character but I need to check for cases where there are multiple last characters that satisfy the condition.

### Edit

I thought I'd be using something like chomp but that only accepts a string. I would like to remove from the right hand side of a string all characters that are not in [a-zA-Z0-9]; not just the last one but potentially 3 or 4. I edited to remove recursively because I figured that implementation would walk back to the first non-occurrence and work to the right.

Ideally, I would like a regex that can do:

```
>["bxy-123___","bab_456-_.","abc__34--"].map { |frag|  frag.gsub(???,'')  }
=>["bxy-123","bab_456","abc__34"]
```

Comment: This is confusing. Can you tell us, in English, what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: I agree with @MarkThomas. I edited this because I thought I understood it (turns out I did not), but the title seems to not match what the question body says.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall:  I rolled back your edit because it seemed to reverse the meaning of the question, but that title does need work.  I'm not sure how to fix it, though.

Comment: @AlanMoore Yea I definitely got the edit wrong. And then rereading it again I just kept getting more confused.

Comment: sorry - had to do something; let me work on it.

Comment: I thought I understood what you wanted to do before I read your edit.  Initially, you said you wanted to convert `"a-c---"` to `"a-cxxx"`.  In your edit you say you want to remove those trailing characters, but you left the first part of the question unchanged.  Which is it?  For the benefit of those who read this in future, please re-edit to clarify, and while you're at it, we don't really need to know that you went out for a meal.

Comment: I'm gsubbing a regex to a character, I used x for description but in my code, will be gsubbing to ''. Obviously, the hard part is the Regex.

Comment: Tim, if you are mapping all characters to the same replacement character, you only need a simple regex to capture the trailing characters.  Then simply count how many there are and replace them with a string of the same number of replacement characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9](?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$)
```

The lookahead says if there are any more characters after the current one (i.e., between the current position and the end of the string), none of them are letters or digits.  But it only replaces one character on each iteration of `gsub`, so each `-` gets replaced with one `x`.

Comment: thx Alan - works perfectly; sorry about any confusion I caused in question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"a-c---".gsub(/(?!.*?\w-\w?)[^a-zA-Z0-9]/, 'x')  #=> "a-cxxx"
```

([View live on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/ulL0k3NqvI))

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without a lookaround:

```
"a-c---".gsub(/([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/, 'x'*$1.size)
  #=> "a-cxxx"
```

By putting `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` in a capture group, `$1 => "---"`.  Since we want to replace each of these characters with `'x'`, we simply replace `"---"` with:

```
'x'*("---").size => 'x'*3 => "xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would to it:

```
p "a-c---".sub(/\W*$/){ |capture| 'x'*capture.size } #=> a-cxxx
```